# Python Procedures

Tags: python, stored-procedures, pascal, procedure

I have developed a graphical Library (in Pascal) and wanted to use it with several other languages. I have tried it with Python and it works.

Here part of the working code:

```
#file fpgui-test.py
from ctypes import*

fpgui = cdll.LoadLibrary("fpgui-32.dll")
fpgui.fpgInitialize()
fpgui.fpgFormCreate(0, -1)
fpgui.fpgFormSetPosition(0, 300,100,400,200)
fpgui.fpgFormWindowTitle(0, 'Hello world!')

fpgui.fpgButtonCreate(0,0,-1) ;
fpgui.fpgButtonSetPosition(0,0, 15, 10 , 150 , 40)
fpgui.fpgButtonSetText(0,0, 'BUTTON1')

fpgui.fpgButtonCreate(0,1,-1) ;
fpgui.fpgButtonSetPosition(0,1, 15, 70 , 150, 40)
fpgui.fpgButtonSetText(0,1, 'Clickme')

fpgui.fpgFormShow(0)
fpgui.fpgRun()
```

But now I want to add some procedures. In Pascal a procedure is declared like this:

```
fpgFormOnClick(index : integer ;TheProc : procedure);
```

And used like this:

```
fpgFormOnClick(0,@TheProc); => how can you translate that in Python ?
```

And, for example, if `TheProc` procedure is like that in Pascal, how do I do it in Python?

```
procedure TheProc;
begin
fpgButtonSetText(0,1,'Test');
end;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the default Free Pascal calling convention is Register. So probably you want type mycallback= procedure; stdcall; or cdecl;

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it.

```
# here we register the events
events={}

# registation function for events
def fpgFormOnClick(index, procedure):
    events[index] = procedure

# emulates fireing of events
def fire(index):
   # check if we have an event registered
   if index in events:
      # call the registered function/procedure
      events[index]()

def TheProc():
    # if you use python 3 use 
    #   print("TheProc")
    print "TheProc"

# register the function
fpgFormOnClick(0,TheProc)

# and fire it
fire(0)
fire(1)
```

Or is your question about how to get the python function called by the DLL?

Comment: Yep, Michael, many thanks. I want to access that library function (fpgFormOnclick(Index : integer ; Proc : Procedure) with Python. The other procedures can be accessed, i only get problem to assign the callback procedure of FormOnClick. I will study your code, maybe everything i want is inside. see you later and many thanks.

Comment: Is that the answer or do you want to add the python function to the dll?

Comment: Yep, Michael, i must study and test your code, i do not know yet if it is what i want. Many thanks and see you later.

Comment: Hum, Michael, sorry, i will have a litle delay, i just have problems with the computer now... I will repair all and test your code. See you later...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution - it was in "CallBack function" in help-doc.

```
#file fpgui-test.py
from ctypes import*

def TheProc():
    fpgui.fpgFormWindowTitle(0, 'Boum')
    return 0

def TheProcBut0():
    fpgui.fpgButtonSetText(0,0, 'Boum also')
    return 0

def TheProcBut1():
    fpgui.fpgButtonSetText(0,1, 'Boum too')
    return 0

CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)

TheProcF = CMPFUNC(TheProc)
TheProcB0 = CMPFUNC(TheProcBut0)
TheProcB1 = CMPFUNC(TheProcBut1)

fpgui = cdll.LoadLibrary("fpgui-32.dll")

fpgui.fpgInitialize()
fpgui.fpgSetStyle('Demo Style')
fpgui.fpgFormCreate(0, -1)
fpgui.fpgFormSetPosition(0, 300,100,400,200)
fpgui.fpgFormWindowTitle(0, 'Hello world!')

fpgui.fpgFormOnClick(0,TheProcF)

fpgui.fpgButtonCreate(0,0,-1) ;
fpgui.fpgButtonSetPosition(0,0, 15, 10 , 150 , 40)
fpgui.fpgButtonSetText(0,0, 'BUTTON1')
fpgui.fpgButtonOnClick(0,0,TheProcB0)

fpgui.fpgButtonCreate(0,1,-1) ;
fpgui.fpgButtonSetPosition(0,1, 15, 70 , 150, 40)
fpgui.fpgButtonSetText(0,1, 'Clickme')
fpgui.fpgButtonOnClick(0,1,TheProcB1)

fpgui.fpgFormShow(0)
fpgui.fpgRun()
```